# website doesnt reload when i mapping host folder to container folder

Tags: docker

I am using VScode. I tried to map the folder by following the command:
**docker run -d -p 5004:3000 -v /app/node_modules -v ${pwd}:/app react-app**
It should reload the website after I save some code in the app. But it doesn't automatically reload. It will only reload after I run the above command one more time. Does anyone know how to use the above command to map the folders and let the website automatically reload?

Comment: Run `npm run start` or similar on your host; don't use Docker for this use case.  When you do run Docker, remove both `-v` options so that you're running the code actually built into the image and you'll have predictable results when deploying.